# How to write the content of a " const char * " in a textfile?

Tags: c, pointers, file-io

If a constant is declared like this

```
const char   *http_range;
```

Then how can I write the content or the value of it in a text file? Could you please show me with syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, that is not "a constant". It's a pointer to constant character data, i.e. a pointer to a read-only string. You can change the pointer, but you can't change the data it's pointing at. For example:

```
FILE *out;
const char *http_range = "Accept: text/*;q=0.3, text/html;q=0.7";

if ((out = fopen("textfile.txt", "w")) != NULL)
{
  fprintf(out, "the range is '%s'\n", http_range);
  fclose(out);
}
```

Note that the above is in C, your question is weirdly double-tagged so I picked C.

Comment: @the_naive You can thank him more by accepting his answer if it helped you.

Comment: @hochl Corrected, thanks. I thought that was what I wrote. :)

Answer (score 4):

In C++ following code will write value in test.txt

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  const char *http_range = "TEST";
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("test.txt");
  myfile << http_range;
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will be not work if in *http_range wwill be 0x00 char

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`fwrite`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/) function.